# How To Parse XML Respond Of Web Service In Andorid

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, web-services, ksoap2

Hi Guys I am new to Ksoap. I manage to some work on the Web Services in android but Now I am unable to find out how can I parse the XML respond of the Web Service Please Help Me.

The XML In Response

```
anyType
{
schema=anyType
{
element=anyType
{
complexType=anyType
{
choice=anyType
{
element=anyType
{
complexType=anyType
{
sequence=anyType
{
element=anyType{}; 
element=anyType{}; 
element=anyType{}; 
element=anyType{}; 
element=anyType{};
element=anyType{}; 
}; }; }; };  };  }; }; 

diffgram=anyType
{
MobileApp=anyType
{
tbl_Vehicles=anyType
{
 ID=1; 
 PlateNumber=95459;
 Latitude=25.167330;
 Longitude=55.237670;
 Status=Driving;
 Location=Sheikh Zayed Rd. Dubai; 
}; 

tbl_Vehicles=anyType
{
ID=2; 
PlateNumber=45926;
Latitude=25.127791; 
Longitude=55.114626;
Status=Parked;
Location=Alpha Tours, Palm Jumeirah, Dubai; 
}; 
}; 
}; 
}
```

My Code Is As Follow

```
public void getVehicleList()
{
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);       

request.addProperty("UserID", id );

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
envelope.dotNet = true;

try 
{
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION_LOGIN, envelope);


    if (envelope.bodyIn instanceof SoapFault) 
    {
        String str = ((SoapFault) envelope.bodyIn).faultstring;
        Log.i("SoapFault", str);
        showDialog("Error", "Their Is Some Problem In Server Response");
    } 
    else 
    {
        SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;

        Log.d("Veh ID 8", "Result = " + response.toString() );
   }
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968111/parsing-soapobject-responst-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're having a hard time because the response is not XML?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I searched it over internet and then I found that its JSON without proper formatting. Do you have any solution for it.

Comment: If you have access to the JSON data as a String, just do something like: JSONObject o = new JSONObject(data); and then start accessing the data through the JSONObject API (like o.getString("schema");)