# Use webservice in Android

Tags: java, c#, android, web-services

I need to send data to a web service that is write in c# .net,
if I use a `c#` program it can get the names of the web service and 
the function that I can use I guess cause it's `java` it can't do the same
as `c#`, if someone know how to do this it's will be great.
thanks for the help!

I use `httpURLConnection` and write this code to send and get the response
from connection.

```
BufferedReader reader = null;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(uri);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + '\n');
        }
        Log.i("","here  "+sb.toString());
        return sb.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("","problem in connection");
        return null;
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, C# web services uses SOAP protocol, so you'll probably need to parse the soap response which will give the information about the web service api:
check this thread:
[Parsing SoapObject Responst in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968111/parsing-soapobject-responst-in-android)